# Get Toggle From Settings.bundle

Tags: ios, settings, bundle

Really simple question. How do I get values from settings.bundle. In this case, a boolean value. I've seen [this link](http://greghaygood.com/2009/03/09/updating-nsuserdefaults-from-settingsbundle) but it's old and I don't know where to put the code. So I experimented a little myself and came up with this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults synchronize];

id toggleSwitchValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"debuger"];
BOOL boolToggle = [toggleSwitchValue boolValue];

if (boolToggle) {

    NSLog(@"Developer: YES");

}

else {

    NSLog(@"Developer: NO");
}
```

But that didn't work. BTW, I placed it in Appdelegate.m under

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

I also tried using [this sample code from apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AppPrefs/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007799) but it was outdated, I followed it and got a bunch of errors

Regards

Comment: That key called 'debuger' looks misspelt.

Comment: I don't like saying it, but I will, FML!!! I DID spell debuger wrong! (I know, it's spelled "debugger"), but I named it "debug", thanks for correcting me

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to use the same keys you provide in `Settings.bundle`.

```
id toggleSwitchValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"debugger"];
```